# No USB mounted even if inserted

Tags: 14.04, usb, mount

My dell system is running with UBUNTU 14.04. Till recently I didn't have a problem with the usb drives. Now when I insert a pendrive or a hard disk, it doesn't mount nor does it show in the file system. I have to go to disks and then mount it. If I do this and plug the drive into a Windows system, it shows that the drive is full and inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your last sentence but the first part sounds like auto-play is turned off. From the `Launcher` select `System Settings` then `Details` and `Removable Media`. The screen below appears:

[image]

When the last option is checked nothing will auto-play when inserted. Uncheck this option and set the others as desired depending on type of media.

Comment: I have checked this option. Usually as soon as I plug in the device, it used to open in the new window and an icon would be displayed on the taskbar as well as the home sidebar. This isn't seen nor is the device opening.